# How can I pair up facts to create new facts?

Tags: xcode, instruments, clips

I'm new to CLIPS and am trying to use it to create a custom Instrument in Xcode to model state changes in an enumeration.

I want to end up with a series of facts which represent the start and end time of the enumeration being in a given state.

I'm emitting an event signpost each time there is a state change within my code, this can be simplified to look like:

```
(deftemplate signpost
    (slot time (type INTEGER))
    (slot state (type STRING))
)
```

I'm trying to pair them up to generate state interval facts which look like:

```
(deftemplate state-interval
    (slot start (type INTEGER))
    (slot duration (type INTEGER))
    (slot state (type STRING))
)
```

Given the input data:

```
(signpost (time 0) (state "one"))
(signpost (time 2) (state "two"))
(signpost (time 5) (state "three"))
(signpost (time 10) (state "four"))
```

I'd expect to see the following output:

```
(state-interval (start 0) (duration 2) (state "one"))
(state-interval (start 2) (duration 3) (state "two"))
(state-interval (start 5) (duration 5) (state "three"))
```

My closest attempt so far looks like:

```
(deftemplate signpost
    (slot time (type INTEGER))
    (slot state (type STRING))
)

(deftemplate state-update
    (slot time (type INTEGER))
    (slot state (type STRING))
)

(deftemplate state-interval
    (slot start (type INTEGER))
    (slot duration (type INTEGER))
    (slot state (type STRING))
)

(defrule update-state
    ?signpost <- (signpost (time ?time) (state ?state))
    (not (state-update (time ?) (state ?)))
    =>
    (retract ?signpost)
    (assert (state-update (time ?time) (state ?state)))
)

(defrule pair-state
    ?signpost <- (signpost (time ?time) (state ?state))
    ?update <- (state-update (time ?time1) (state ?state1))
    =>
    (modify ?update (time ?time) (state ?state))
    (retract ?signpost)
    (bind ?duration (- ?time1 ?time))
    (assert (state-interval (start ?time1) (duration ?duration) (state ?state1)))
)

(deffacts sample-data
    (signpost (time 0) (state "one"))
    (signpost (time 2) (state "two"))
    (signpost (time 5) (state "three"))
    (signpost (time 10) (state "four"))
)
```

I get the following output:

```
FIRE    1 update-state: f-4,*
<== f-4     (signpost (time 10) (state "four"))
==> f-5     (state-update (time 10) (state "four"))
==> Activation 0      pair-state: f-3,f-5
==> Activation 0      pair-state: f-2,f-5
==> Activation 0      pair-state: f-1,f-5
<== Activation 0      update-state: f-3,*
<== Activation 0      update-state: f-2,*
<== Activation 0      update-state: f-1,*
FIRE    2 pair-state: f-1,f-5
<== f-5     (state-update (time 10) (state "four"))
<== Activation 0      pair-state: f-2,f-5
<== Activation 0      pair-state: f-3,f-5
==> Activation 0      update-state: f-1,*
==> Activation 0      update-state: f-2,*
==> Activation 0      update-state: f-3,*
==> f-6     (state-update (time 0) (state "one"))
==> Activation 0      pair-state: f-3,f-6
==> Activation 0      pair-state: f-2,f-6
==> Activation 0      pair-state: f-1,f-6
<== Activation 0      update-state: f-3,*
<== Activation 0      update-state: f-2,*
<== Activation 0      update-state: f-1,*
<== f-1     (signpost (time 0) (state "one"))
<== Activation 0      pair-state: f-1,f-6
==> f-7     (state-interval (start 10) (duration 10) (state "four"))
FIRE    3 pair-state: f-2,f-6
<== f-6     (state-update (time 0) (state "one"))
<== Activation 0      pair-state: f-3,f-6
==> Activation 0      update-state: f-2,*
==> Activation 0      update-state: f-3,*
==> f-8     (state-update (time 2) (state "two"))
==> Activation 0      pair-state: f-3,f-8
==> Activation 0      pair-state: f-2,f-8
<== Activation 0      update-state: f-3,*
<== Activation 0      update-state: f-2,*
<== f-2     (signpost (time 2) (state "two"))
<== Activation 0      pair-state: f-2,f-8
==> f-9     (state-interval (start 0) (duration -2) (state "one"))
FIRE    4 pair-state: f-3,f-8
<== f-8     (state-update (time 2) (state "two"))
==> Activation 0      update-state: f-3,*
==> f-10    (state-update (time 5) (state "three"))
==> Activation 0      pair-state: f-3,f-10
<== Activation 0      update-state: f-3,*
<== f-3     (signpost (time 5) (state "three"))
<== Activation 0      pair-state: f-3,f-10
==> f-11    (state-interval (start 2) (duration -3) (state "two"))
<== Focus MAIN
4 rules fired        Run time is 0.00531400000909343 seconds.
752.728640036717 rules per second.
5 mean number of facts (5 maximum).
1 mean number of instances (1 maximum).
2 mean number of activations (4 maximum).
```

Resulting in:

```
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-7     (state-interval (start 10) (duration 10) (state "four"))
f-9     (state-interval (start 0) (duration -2) (state "one"))
f-10    (state-update (time 5) (state "three"))
f-11    (state-interval (start 2) (duration -3) (state "two"))
For a total of 5 facts.
```

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here. In my mind I'm assuming that Xcode is going to be feeding me in these signpost facts sequentially over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
         CLIPS (6.31 4/1/19)
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate signpost
    (slot time (type INTEGER))
    (slot state (type STRING)))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate state-interval
    (slot start (type INTEGER))
    (slot duration (type INTEGER))
    (slot state (type STRING)))
CLIPS> 
(defrule find-interval

   ;; Find the first signpost

   (signpost (time ?time1) (state ?state))

   ;; And a second signpost that comes later

   (signpost (time ?time2&:(> ?time2 ?time1)))

   ;; And there's no other signpost between the two

   (not (signpost (time ?time3&:(> ?time3 ?time1)
                              &:(< ?time3 ?time2))))
   =>

   (assert (state-interval (start ?time1)
                           (duration (- ?time2 ?time1))
                           (state ?state))))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts sample-data
    (signpost (time 0) (state "one"))
    (signpost (time 2) (state "two"))
    (signpost (time 5) (state "three"))
    (signpost (time 10) (state "four")))
CLIPS> (watch rules)
CLIPS> (watch facts)
CLIPS> (watch activations)
CLIPS> (reset)
<== f-0     (initial-fact)
==> f-0     (initial-fact)
==> f-1     (signpost (time 0) (state "one"))
==> f-2     (signpost (time 2) (state "two"))
==> Activation 0      find-interval: f-1,f-2,*
==> f-3     (signpost (time 5) (state "three"))
==> Activation 0      find-interval: f-2,f-3,*
==> f-4     (signpost (time 10) (state "four"))
==> Activation 0      find-interval: f-3,f-4,*
CLIPS> (run)
FIRE    1 find-interval: f-3,f-4,*
==> f-5     (state-interval (start 5) (duration 5) (state "three"))
FIRE    2 find-interval: f-2,f-3,*
==> f-6     (state-interval (start 2) (duration 3) (state "two"))
FIRE    3 find-interval: f-1,f-2,*
==> f-7     (state-interval (start 0) (duration 2) (state "one"))
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (signpost (time 0) (state "one"))
f-2     (signpost (time 2) (state "two"))
f-3     (signpost (time 5) (state "three"))
f-4     (signpost (time 10) (state "four"))
f-5     (state-interval (start 5) (duration 5) (state "three"))
f-6     (state-interval (start 2) (duration 3) (state "two"))
f-7     (state-interval (start 0) (duration 2) (state "one"))
For a total of 8 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Ahhh, that conditional syntax was what I was missing. I guess each LHS match is taken in turn, so CLIPs won't cycle through all possible combinations. It makes a lot of sense - thank you.